# loading icon logic brakes widget tree _key.currentState becomes null

Tags: flutter, loading, statefulwidget

I have scaffold with animated list that is dinamicaly constructed.
It was working fine right before I tried to implement loading icon feature.

This function builds blocks of animated list

```
void _addItem(someItem) {
         _items.insert(0, "${jsonEncode(someItem)} ");
      _key.currentState!.insertItem(
        0,
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      );
    }
  }
```

Now when I put small loading icon feature inside widget tree function fails to build saying
_key.currentState is null.

This is my widget Tree

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('app'),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: deviceSize.height,
        width: deviceSize.width,
        child:
            

       _isShowLoadingIcon
            ? Image.asset('assets/images/Loading_icon.gif')
            :
            

            Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: AnimatedList(
      key: _key,
      initialItemCount: 0,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
        return SizeTransition(
          key: UniqueKey(),
          sizeFactor: animation,
          child: Card(
```

If we do not use

_isShowLoadingIcon
? Image.asset('assets/images/Loading_icon.gif')
:

Then the rest of the code will work fine. How can I fix this problem ?

Added check for _isShowLoadingIcon

```
 void _addItem(someItem) {
    if (_isShowLoadingIcon) return;
    print('_isShowLoadingIcon = ${_isShowLoadingIcon}');
             _items.insert(0, "${jsonEncode(someItem)} ");
          _key.currentState!.insertItem(
            0,
            duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
          );
        }
      }
```

App still crashing
printing that _isShowLoadingIcon = false
and then crash at line where _key.currentState is somehow null
Null check operator used on a null value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that _key.currentState is null when you are showing the loading icon instead of the AnimatedList() with your _key. You might check if your key state is currently null before accessing ity, e. g.

```dart
void _addItem(someItem) {
  if(_key.currentState == null) return; 
  
  _items.insert(0, "${jsonEncode(someItem)} ");
  _key.currentState!.insertItem(0, duration: const Duration(seconds: 1));
}
```

Comment: did that
    if (_isShowLoadingIcon) return;
    print('_isShowLoadingIcon = ${_isShowLoadingIcon}');

Resul is that right before crash I get last print event
I/flutter (12740): _isShowLoadingIcon = false
then app crashes because of 
      _key.currentState!.insertItem(  >>> Null check operator used on a null value

Comment: I edited the answer to check the key state instead of _isShowLoadingIcon. Does that work for you? Or do you need to add items while the AnimatedList is not mounted?

Comment: no that's fine. I just don't draw that part of widget if it is not ready and moved my loading icon deeper beneath that part so it wont bother animated list which will just not load at that moment, so my problem is solved that way :) Thank you!